# How to select only one item from an artboard and then export?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm having issues trying to get one item to export from an artboard. I'm only wanting the highlighted part to be exported as a .png. I've tried selecting only that object, which I can't unless I hide all the groups. Otherwise it selects everything within that layer...so everything.

Then after I have hidden all surrounding objects and selected that item, I adjusted the artboard to fit solely around the object I want to export. The entire original artboard size exported.

I cannot figure this out. I've watched many videos to try and figure it out. Sorry for the newb question.

This is the document. I just want the highlighted part to export.
[image]

This is what exports
[image]

Comment: Copy > New Document > Paste > Export > Close without saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*File > Export Selection* might be useful for what you want.

There's no need to hide any layers, just make sure everything you want to export is grouped. If you want to export a background as well, you will need to use a filled rectangle, and also group that with each object.  Using *Export Selection* ensures that the export is based on the selection only, even if the groups overlap each other.

Here's an example:

Each asset here is a group (including a background rectangle). I selected each group in turn, and did *File > Export Selection*.

[image]

You can also use the Asset Export panel and click and drag assets into it. Then you can export directly from there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think that is part of my issue. The designer grouped the entire document as one group. How can I regroup items?

Comment: @Paul Do Object > Ungroup. You may need to repeat this if there are multiple groups within groups for example, then select the objects you want to be grouped, and hit Object > Group.

Comment: The "Ungroup" option under "Object" is grayed out, not letting me select it.

Comment: @Paul - Use the Selection Tool (V) to select the group first, so you can tell Illustrator to ungroup it.  If you are still having problems doing this, then it may depend on how the graphics were constructed. Perhaps speak to your designer if you can't work it out. It's hard to answer this without access to the AI file.

Comment: I was doing all that. I just figured out what else needed selected to be able to ungroup. There was a blue box needed to be checked to select art. I did that and with your help, it worked. Thank you!